How to read the written data from the Servlet's Response
1.Now, I have this Response object, and I'm using the Response.getWriter object to write to it and some JSON data.
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.write("hello world");
writer.flush();

2.Because I'm unit testing this code, I need to read the data written to the response. Now that I can get the response object, how do I get the data I just wrote?
I don't have any way to do it.

Possibly a duplicate of Testing my java servlet with Junit?.
